# meaning of a sentence in simak's project mastodon chpt.1

Tags: meaning, slang

I am wondering the meaning of the following sentence found at the end of chapter 1 in Simak's [Project Mastodon](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/22216/22216-h/22216-h.htm)!:

> Snide item in smug, smart-alecky gossip column: Saucers are passé at the Pentagon. There’s another mystery that’s got the high brass very high.

This looks like a cutscene to the newspapers of something like that, but i cannot understand the meaning

Comment: This is better asked at our sister site, [ELL.se], but short story is that someone writes a gossip column (that is, a regular feature, typically daily or weekly) in the newspaper. This gossip column usually is written in a snarky, smug way (which is an appropriate style for a gossip column). This week's gossip column reports that the senior leadership of the US' military (the *top brass* [think brass badges, medals], who work at *the Pentagon* building in DC) have lost interest in UFOs (*saucers*) in favor of some newer, weirder mysterious phenomenon.

Comment: PS: *cut scenes* usually apply to filmed media, not to literature or text in general.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And thanks for pointing the other site as well.